# Mule ESB: Evaluating Integers in Mule expression

Tags: mule, esb

I have a database table that I am using a DB adapter to extract my payload from here is the definition:

```
CREATE TABLE PriceTickets(ID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 0)  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, PRICE INTEGER,DESTINATION VARCHAR(255))");
```

Now I in my configuration I am firing up my database inbound endpoint & trying to apply logic on payload where if the Price value is greater than 750 to do forward to a queue here is the logic:

```
<flow name="ExpreFlow2" doc:name="ExpreFlow2"> 
    <jdbc-ee:inbound-endpoint   queryTimeout="-1" doc:name="Database" connector-ref="jdbcConnector" queryKey="selectAll" pollingFrequency="10000">
            <jdbc-ee:transaction action="NONE"/>
    </jdbc-ee:inbound-endpoint>
   doc:name="Expression"></expression-transformer>-->  
    <!-- <logger level="INFO" message="Payload is #[message:payload]" doc:name="Logger1"></logger> -->
    <foreach doc:name="Foreach">
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
    <when expression="#[message.payload[0]['price'] > 750]" > 
       <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain"> 
            <request-reply timeout="5000"> 
               <jms:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="jmsConnector" queue="Queue1"></jms:outbound-endpoint> 
               <jms:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="jmsConnector" queue="Queue2"></jms:inbound-endpoint>  
             </request-reply>  
       </processor-chain>
    </when>
```

However I find that I get the following error when trying to run this flow:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Character cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
    at org.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.getCollectionPropertyAO(
```

Tried other combinations of specifying the integer comparison, none worked , any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: I am guessing it is because I am not using #[map-payload:price] in my when as I am getting a map from the database . Could anybody confirm?

Comment: You're mixing old style expressions and MEL: use `#[message.payload]` not `#[message:payload]`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `foreach` in place to iterate through the rows so the `[0]` in your expression is probably superfluous.

You should be able to reach the column value directly with:

```
#[message.payload.price > 750]
```

Comment: <jdbc-ee:inbound-endpoint   ...    </jdbc-ee:inbound-endpoint>
    
   
             <foreach doc:name="Foreach">
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
    <when expression="#[message.price > 750]" >                                                                           Got:                                                                 Exception stack is:
1. [Error: could not access: price; in class: org.mule.el.context.MessageContext]
[Near : {... message.price > 750 ....}]                                                                     
             ^

Comment: Same problem here David ,it is not able to access price off the map even though I can print the price a few lines above

Comment: Sorry my bad, I meant `message.payload.price`.

Comment: @DavidDosset                                                        Finally I tried `code`   <foreach doc:name="Foreach">
     <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="#[message.payload.PRICE > 750]"> 
       <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain"> 
           <logger level="INFO" message="Print 1" doc:name="Logger"/> 
       </processor-chain>
    </when> `code`                                                              got 'code' Exception stack is:
[Error: could not access: PRICE; in class: java.lang.String]
[Near : {... message.payload.PRICE > 750 ....}] `code`